# Does sin n have a maximum value for natural number n?

Tags: math, numbers, discrete-mathematics, rational-numbers

In formal, does there exist [image] such that [image] for all [image]?

Comment: This better goes to http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a purely mathematical question (structure of real numbers) and thus belongs to math.se

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about mathematics, not programming or software development.

Answer (score 2):

No, $\pi$ and thus $\pi/2$ are irrational, thus the (additive) equivalence classes of the integers modulo $2\pi$ are dense in $\Bbb R$ and thus approach infinitesimally, but never reach $\pi/2$.

---

The fundamental fact is that for any given number x the set of numbers {mx+n : m,n integer} is either

- an arithmetic sequence {mr : r integer} which implies and is equivalent to x as a multiple of r being rational, or
- dense in the real numbers, which by the first case happens for all irrational x.